# Problems downloading files IOS/android 7

Tags: android, ios, json, http

I am building a web API for a webapp with a messaging system in which users can attach files to their messages.

When the recipient tries to download the attached files it works on all desktop browsers, and android phones with android older than android 7.0.

But for iPhones and newer android devices, the download doesn't work.

For iPhone nothing happens at all, even though I'm sure the phone receives the http-response.
On android 7.0, the browser gives me this error: "{file-name} download failed due to an unknown error".

My HTTP response looks like this when trying to GET a single attachment:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 04 May 2017 07:37:55 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 07:38:59 GMT
Connection: close

({
    "id": 1043,
    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "image.jpg",
    "size": 1331138,
    "data": "[base64encoded-file]"
})
```

Comment: `My HTTP response looks like this:` What is that? The message with the attachments? Or what? The response to a request for one attachment? Unclear.

Comment: the get response for a single attachment

Comment: Then what is the problem/question? You get json and the json contains the file base64 encoded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I outlined the question/problem in the original question. The problem is that when the "download" button is pressed; nothing happens. I can see that my API is indeed delivering the response to the client, but since I cannot debug on the iPhone, I do not know what to do now.

Comment: Well you said it was on Android. I blame you posting problems for Android and iOs in one post. And Download button? You did not mention a button before. And if this is not a programming question. If you are not programming an Android app then this is the wrong site for your problem.

Comment: Honestly I do not see any will to help in any of your comments.
I am programming the backend/API for a website where employees can send and receive files, much like you can do with facebook. This is done through a browser. When you click the download button on the recieved file, I see that my API recieves a HTTP.Get request and creates the response I posted in my question. But on the client (iPhones/Android 7.0 devices), the download fails, even though it completes without any error on ALL other platforms.